# RadGrid - batch edit mode not firing on click

Tags: telerik, radgrid

Edit mode is not firing when cell in clicked

```
 <telerik:RadGrid RenderMode="Lightweight" ShowGroupPanel="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="grd_log" BorderWidth="0" Font-Size="Smaller" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowSorting="True" Width="100%" ShowFooter="True" AllowPaging="True" runat="server" PageSize="250" PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True"  AllowAutomaticInserts="false"
                        OnNeedDataSource="grd_log_NeedDataSource"
                        OnBatchEditCommand="grd_log_BatchEditCommand">
                    <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false"></GroupingSettings>
                    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" ShowFooter="false" ShowHeader="true" DataKeyNames="bol_number" EditMode="Batch" AllowAutomaticInserts="false">
                        <BatchEditingSettings EditType="Cell" HighlightDeletedRows="true" OpenEditingEvent="Click" >
                            </BatchEditingSettings>
                        <CommandItemSettings ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" />
                        <Columns>...
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to test the following demo and see whether the problem is there: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/batch-editing/defaultcs.aspx.

If not, please

- Compare your code with the one of the demo.
- Check for JavaScript errors in the DevTools console (F12).

If yes, please provide the steps to reproduce the issue in the live demo. Are there any errors and under which browser do you test?